# Extracting from delimited string

Tags: java

Would appreciate comment on whether this is the best/recommended way to parse a pipe-delimited string for particular keys.
In a low-latency system which runs this operation for every request - inefficiency is expensive.

```
 public String extractFields(String key,String comment){
        if(comment!=null){
            for(String test:comment.split("\\|")){
                if(test.contains(key)){
                    return test.substring(test.indexOf(key)+key.length()).trim();
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be posted to codereview.stackexchange.com (and be more precise on what the input is, what the desired output is, and where his comment comes from)

Comment: Unrelated, but I'd check for `comment == null` and return early if it is, and avoid the extra nesting, and IMO make the precondition easier to spot.

Comment: If you want to use split, use a compiled Pattern to split, that is initialized only once, instead of `String::split`, as it will compile the pattern every time it's called. This would be true for anything taking a regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, the split and search seems a bit pointless to me.

Why not:

- `indexOf()` of the key to get its location, test if this is valid
- If valid, from that location, do `indexOf()` to the next `|`
- Return a substring of the above region.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Nim's answer, here is an implementation of the faster way to do it:

```
public String extractField(String key, String comment) {
    if (key == null || comment == null)
        return null;
    int i = comment.indexOf(key);
    if (i < 0) // Does not contain the key
        return null;
    String result = comment.substring(i + 1);
    i = result.indexOf('|');
    if (i >= 0)
        result = result.substring(0, i);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: You don't need to do two `substrings`, you can do it in one.. ;)